# Shrinking Triangles

Tags: code-golf, source-layout, code-generation

Write an infinite list of triangle codes, defined as code where the i-th line has i bytes for all lines, such that the i-th code generates (i-1)th code and has 1 more line than the (i-1)th code.

The score is the number of lines in the initial code. Lowest score wins.

For example, if

```
.
..
...
....
```

is outputted by

```
.
..
...
....
print
```

which is outputted by

```
.
..
...
....
print
print.
```

and so on, then the score is 4.

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21963/)

Comment: Does each step need to be done in the same language?

Comment: Are we allowed to read our own source code?

Comment: Why is this called "shrinking triangles"? Surely it's about growing triangles?

Comment: Are we allowed to output the source code with a trailing newline? E.g. `x\nxx` -> `x\nxx\nxxx\n`?

Comment: @pxeger You should output smaller one. Is there default for trailing newline?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Same language. Not quine.

Comment: Oh I see. How can I write an "infinite list of triangle codes" then? Do I need to design a mechanism for generating infinitely large triangles?

Comment: Should I read the question as this? Write a program \$P\$ in language \$L_1\$, take input \$n\$ \$(n > k \ge 0)\$, output \$P(n)\$. The output \$P(n)\$ contains \$n\$ lines. The \$i\$th (1-indexed) line of \$P(n)\$ contains \$i\$ characters. When execute \$P(n)\$ as a program in language \$L_2\$, it outputs \$P(n-1)\$. Your score is \$k\$ while the lower the better.

Comment: If this is not code-golf, you should remove the code-golf tag and add correct tag for winning criterion.

Comment: I suppose the smallest output just needs to be a valid triangle, but not valid code anymore. Is that correct?

Comment: @pxeger You should convince others that the list exist, maybe by providing a generator

Comment: @tsh Don't smallest triangle = shortest code, though it's generated one?

Comment: Does the triangle need to finish every line?  Or is it ok if there are some lines which are short? Of course still scored based on the size of the triangle.

Comment: @WheatWizard the i-th line has i bytes. Are you trying to slice one byte from end each time?

Comment: No it's just way easier to do what I want if I don't add spaces to the end of the lines to pad them out to the length.

Comment: @WheatWizard I only meant a reason that allow that is a bad idea

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), Score  <s>10</s>  9

Below is an example starting point with 15 lines. Bigger triangles are obtained by padding the end with 0's while preserving the final `` `) ``.

```javascript
0
f=
_=>
  `0
${`f=
`+f}`.
/*###*/
replace(
/..\n.+$/
,'`)'||`00
00000000000
000000000000
0000000000000
00000000000000
0000000000000`)
```

which is eventually reduced to:

```javascript
0
f=
_=>
  `0
${`f=
`+f}`.
/*###*/
replace(
/..\n.+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xclBDsIgFATQ/T8FCU0KrQIXwJOY@Al@jIZAA6Yb69lRV2o9gLOaN3Nxs6u@nKfrNuUjtWYgWDjYHTCGBrobPoljuKMCPXDOBw2Fpug8CdBK7ZMaOw2bHmW/LGgMmHc@@zdWWhFl8znVHEnFfBKFKrMsCCnhd6bZxVeVf77bAw)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 278 lines

The output of this 279-byte program:

```r
'->w;s=substring;`+`=paste0;x=nchar(w);y=s(w,1,138);z=sQuote(s(w,1,x-1))+y;for(i in 2:nchar(z)-2)cat("#"+s(z,1,i),sep=intToUtf8(10));cat(z).'->w;s=substring;`+`=paste0;x=nchar(w);y=s(w,1,138);z=sQuote(s(w,1,x-1))+y;for(i in 2:nchar(z)-2)cat("#"+s(z,1,i),sep=intToUtf8(10));cat(z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zY7LCoMwFER/JaSL5uIDtZvSkEJx66a0XdcH0QYkkdxYHz9vFX@iyzlzBsYuSn8VqrKV7DFhiNK1pirWVBVONsZORBCape9bllGf7N2GUgqwHIPrwFFgX6KzSjc893LRFehkxEehq09h2QB8EsgGP/bj0xn4LPDeGyfZzsYgBvAmXhvLFFGaJJd9N0OQwHqC0QP1kM2rq8BH2Qml3dO8XH1mcQTAN2eG8I@@LMsP)

Each successive program is created by adding an
additional character character (any character) at position 139 of the final line of the 'base' program.

**Ungolfed program generator:**

```r
w='->w;s=substring;`+`=paste0;x=nchar(w);y=s(w,1,138);z=sQuote(s(w,1,x-1))+y;for(i in 2:nchar(z)-2)cat("#"+s(z,1,i),sep=intToUtf8(10));cat(z).'
                                # define string w as the golfed working program code, 
                                # appended with extra characters to generate 
                                # successively longer versions;
`+`=paste0                      # redefine `+` to concatenate strings;
x=nchar(w)                      # Now, get x = the number of characters of w
y=substring(w,1,138)            # define y as the working program code without any extra characters
z=sQuote(substring(w,1,x-1))+y  # define z as the previous full working program: that is,
                                # the definition of w minus 1 character, plus the program code.
for(i in 2:nchar(z)-2){         # Loop up to the length of z minus 1
  cat("#"+s(z,1,i),sep="\n")    # printing its prefixes after a "#"
}                               # (so these are all comments in the outputted program), 
cat(z)                          # finally output the previous program code.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), score 5

The pattern repeats like this:

```sh
#
h\
ea\
d -\
n-1 \
$0 ###
#######
########
#########
##########
###########
############
#############
# ad infinitum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9fmSsjhis1MYYrRUE3hitP11AhhkvFQEFZWZlLGQJgNIKBxEJmorBROUCeQmKKQmZeWmZeZklp7v//AA)

With this as the ultimate program:

```sh
#
h\
ea\
d -\
n-1 \
$0 ###
```

- `#`: comments, ignored
- `h\ea\d -\n-1 \$0`: the backslashes and line breaks are eaten up to produce `head -n-1 $0`

  - `head`: print the first \$ n \$ lines
  - `$0`: of the current program
  - `-n-1`: with \$ n = -1 \$, which is treated as "all but the last"

Comment: Runned your code score should be 5?

Comment: Oh, the score should be the length of the output of the final program, not the final program itself, ok

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) (GHC 8.4.1, `-cpp`), score 28

This is the initial triangle (the first line is actually a space).

```hs
 
q\
=p\
rint
p=pu\
tStr;\
f(x:y)\
|length\
 y>25=p"\
f ">>q('.\
'<$y);f s=\
p$show s++"\
]\n";l=putSt\
rLn;main=   do
l. concat<>map\
M_((>>p",\\\10"\
).p.show)$init[ \
" \nq\\\n=p\\\n",\
"rint\np=pu\\\nt",\
"Str;\\\nf(x:y)\\",\
"\n|length\\\n y>2",\
"5=p\"\\\nf \">>q('",\
".\\\n'<$y);f s=\\\n",\
"q$show s++\"\\\n]\\n",\
"\";l=putSt\\\nrLn;mai",\
"n=   do\nl. concat<>ma",\
"p\\\nM_((>>p\",\\\\\\10",\
"\"\\\n).p.show)$init[ \\",\
```

To obtain the the 29-lines triangle we add the following line.

```hs
".........................."]
```

From the 30<sup>th</sup> line onwards, the pattern becomes regular.

```hs
 
q\
=p\
rint
p=pu\
tStr;\
f(x:y)\
|length\
 y>25=p"\
f ">>q('.\
'<$y);f s=\
p$show s++"\
]\n";l=putSt\
rLn;main=   do
l. concat<>map\
M_((>>p",\\\10"\
).p.show)$init[ \
" \nq\\\n=p\\\n",\
"rint\np=pu\\\nt",\
"Str;\\\nf(x:y)\\",\
"\n|length\\\n y>2",\
"5=p\"\\\nf \">>q('",\
".\\\n'<$y);f s=\\\n",\
"q$show s++\"\\\n]\\n",\
"\";l=putSt\\\nrLn;mai",\
"n=   do\nl. concat<>ma",\
"p\\\nM_((>>p\",\\\\\\10",\
"\"\\\n).p.show)$init[ \\",\
".........................."]
f ".........................."
f "..........................."
f "............................"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHdS8MwFMXf81dcwmAtc8GJgti1LwoqKD7om3dI6Lo12N2ma/wY@Ldbb9POD8TZh0DPuTk5vyTX9WNWFI1Z2XLt4Ew7ra5LKs0cxmOoDaUZ3F3ewLzMaho6yPVzBucXp3CsDtWkAVGhiC2KtSEnbGyfULhbt45QLILXk02I4q3IaOlyFLBJDo5iK9kCmSRVMFQohtPBJowWUMco7KDOyxeoRyOemSHJqOBAjuP4K4pW2lAMwFVEoSAtKdVumqw0n379EARJYuUeIk72eXeorGrDwoEh4@4BhQSkim3itrzyqJBtaSTfmiXnNV@e//r66EWkLQU7LYdXGQalnwXsgLysWukb1/a06hOv2zXbGvgFylKP6p2eF@kHsLc8Rc@NHrxj7wJb89cddCzqz0/O2pfZ4e@2//WVbJr3dFHoZd2MU2s/AA)

You can find a program to generate arbitrarily large triangles [here](https://tio.run/##dVJda8IwFH3fr7gEwRY1OEUYq80v0KftzRQpNbVlaRrTyCbst69LUhutbIE2H/fk3HtObpE2H4zzVrNK8lQziAEBFSdKqYil/atSaCpkLM92p9@0iuwiD75eL6FdfXMmjrqwS7iQxcpcQw4BFBFyCsbY7sbr0SWMcmhiu5Ojpqg/oZlMOmxiPooibrKYDC7tRkRVWooYAA41FRxDVoss1WtSpa6w7T4ICDHJptSN53nHFWKJLXs4KkWpd0Adt5mcKi@sO552kxPpVTqhPnZVPBBNfXRgQO@Bj65cKtRft7V0nngEvsYG/gxqO928ulElQ4yN3Ll3Z6CH9E4@WOnjvSe9rdQbe7P3LtsV/YfZvTeode93qJ8ABKxnoFh62AizK3N7AIsX0AUTwJSqFaD3uoamSjlHwHjDQJ4VC0IDd6oU9C3aExBPcAUg4@a/g6LElPTAbDppu4eAljAjniUH80TSdoRpXfMsuxXGZRKGsFvOMRZJ2y4XP1nO02PTzjIpfwE).

### How?

We use the `-cpp` flag to allow line breaking in the source code by means of `\`. GHC 8.4.1 is necessary since it is the first version to export the `(<>)` `Semigroup` operator in `Prelude`. My answer uses a variation of [this clever technique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161036/82619) typically employed in quines. Here is the de-triangularized code.

```hs
q=print
p=putStr
f(x:y)|length y>25=p"f ">>q('.'<$y)
f s=p$show s++"]\n"
l=putStrLn
main=do
    l.concat<>mapM_((>>p",\\\10").p.show)$init[
        " \nq\\\n=p\\\n",
        "rint\np=pu\\\nt",
        "Str;\\\nf(x:y)\\",
        "\n|length\\\n y>2",
        "5=p\"\\\nf \">>q('",
        ".\\\n'<$y);f s=\\\n",
        "q$show s++\"\\\n]\\n",
        "\";l=putSt\\\nrLn;mai",
        "n=   do\nl. concat<>ma",
        "p\\\nM_((>>p\",\\\\\\10",
        "\"\\\n).p.show)$init[ \\",
        ".........................."]
    f ".........................."
    f "..........................."
    f "............................"
    f "............................."
```

The part before `f ".........................."` defines a function `f` and then prints itself (minus the last line `".........................."]`). The behaviour of `f` depends on the length of its argument: if the length is `26` then it prints `".........................."]`, otherwise if prints `f "....[...]....."`, where the number of dots is one less then the length of its argument. In both cases, `f` is basically printing the line just before its invocation.

By the way, making sure that the strings of the list had the correct length was a total nightmare. You think adding some random spaces to the code above would be enough? No no no! I spent way too much time trying all the possible combinations of `putStr` and `putStrLn`, moving things around to change the number of `\` in the code. The winning move was finally replacing a `\n` with `\10`, and after that everything was magically aligned.

Comment: Can you make a link where we can try-out the program?  I tried pasting it into TIO but it gave me an error...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yes, sorry, I forgot. Edited.